# Calculating positions of nodes relative to a known point

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

If I know all the distances between a set of nodes and I also know that one of the nodes is at location (0,0), using the distances between the nodes, can I calculate the absolute positions between all of the nodes? I feel that this will involve some form of trilateration but only a single node position is known. Will I need an iterative algorithm to eventually find a unique solution?

[image]

Comment: Given a valid solution, all rotations of it around the origin and flips of it through a line containing the origin are also valid solutions, so you can't distinguish these solutions.  But I think that if you choose any 2 other points (besides the origin) and fix (i) the angle between the origin and point #2 and (ii) which side of this line point #3 should lie on, the solution is unique (assuming no noise).

Comment: Ah, I see. If I apply boundaries stating that I can only be to the right and below the origin node (Node 0), does this alleviate this problem? Also with respect to noise, I'd be satisfied with a "there abouts" result as I can imagine a problem like this has a looooooooong analytical answer.

Comment: That won't work in general, since the origin could be near the centre of a larger object.

Comment: Restricting to a specific quadrant isn't enough. For example, suppose that you have point A at distance 1 from the origin and point B at distance 2 from the origin and distance 1 from A. Then the three points are in a straight line, which could be at any angle within the quadrant. (Actually, why did I take three points instead of just one? Oh well, I've typed it out, now.)

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you David. Would I therefore be able to alleviate the rotational problem if I knew that all of the nodes were all pointing "north" (upward in the image), combining the nodes heading and distance from others?

Comment: Why do you want the solution to be unique? What do you want to do with the coordinates of the points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an algorithm that determines a configuration if one exists, given a distance matrix. It repeatedly uses [circle-circle intersection](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/)  to triangulate new nodes based on their distance to the first, second and third. As others have mentioned in comments, the first three points have some degree of freedom, which I've made assumptions for, in line with yours.

The code assumes all points are unique and invariant to changes smaller than a certain $\epsilon$.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const double epsilon = 0.00001;

struct Point {
    double x, y;
};

double dist(Point p, Point q) {
    return sqrt((p.x - q.x) * (p.x - q.x) + (p.y - q.y) * (p.y - q.y));
}

vector<Point> intersections(Point p, Point q, double pr, double qr) {
    double d = dist(p, q);
    if(pr + qr < d) return vector<Point>();
    if(min(pr, qr) + d + epsilon < max(pr, qr)) return vector<Point>();
    double a = (pr * pr - qr * qr + d * d) / (2.0 * d),
        h = sqrt(pr * pr - a * a);

    Point m = { p.x + (a * (q.x - p.x)) / d, 
        p.y + (a * (q.y - p.y)) / d },
        r = { m.x + (h * (q.y - p.y) / d),
            m.y - (h * (q.x - p.x)) / d },
        s = { m.x - (h * (q.y - p.y) / d),
            m.y + (h * (q.x - p.x)) / d };

    return {r, s};
}

int main() {
    int N;
    cin >> N;

    vector<vector<double> > adj(N, vector<double>(N));

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            cin >> adj[i][j];
        }
    }

    vector<Point> ps(N);

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if(i == 0) ps[i] = {0.0, 0.0};
        else if(i == 1) ps[i] = { adj[0][1], 0.0 };
        else if(i == 2) {
            vector<Point> is = intersections(ps[0], ps[1], adj[0][2], adj[1][2]);
            if(is.empty()) {
                cout << "Invalid" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
            ps[i] = is[0];
        } else {
            vector<Point> first = intersections(ps[0], ps[1], adj[0][i], adj[1][i]),
                second = intersections(ps[1], ps[2], adj[1][i], adj[2][i]);
            if(first.empty() || second.empty()) {
                cout << "Invalid" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
            if(min(dist(first[0], second[0]), dist(first[0], second[1])) < epsilon) ps[i] = first[0];
            else if(min(dist(first[1], second[0]), dist(first[1], second[1])) < epsilon) ps[i] = first[1];
            else {
                cout << "Invalid" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        if(abs(dist(ps[i], ps[j]) - adj[i][j]) > epsilon) {
            cout << "Invalid" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    cout << "Valid" << endl;
    for(const Point &p : ps) {
        cout << p.x << " " << p.y << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I haven't had time to comment the code. If you want me to, leave a comment. I took your drawing as a sample (which is invalid) and wrote another sample myself:

```
4
0 10 11 10
10 0 8 11
11 8 0 8
10 11 8 0

Invalid

4
0 4 5 3
4 0 3 5
5 3 0 4
3 5 4 0

Valid
0 0
4 0
4 -3
0 -3
```

As you can see, a valid configuration is printed if one exists. The complexity of the construction algorithm is $O(N)$, but we need to check if all matrix entries are valid after construction, which is $O(N^2)$.

Comment: Great job on the code! Would you be able to explain the inputs? I gather that 4 defined the amount of inputs and the remaining digits are distances between the input node and the others? Obviously inputting valid values will produce some form of useful result showing node locations?

Comment: The first line of input contains one positive integer $N$, the number of nodes. Then follow $N$ lines of $N$ real numbers each, with the value at the $i^{th}$ row, and $j^{th}$ column describing the distance from node $i$ to node $j$. You can see that the matrix needs to have a zero-diagonal, and be symmetrical for it to be valid.